# Unreal Engine 5.1 does not compile with CppStandard set to c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, unreal-engine5

In a fresh "Blank" project setting "CppStandard = CppStandardVersion.Cpp20;" in "*.Build.cs" leads to compile errors:

> 0>/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Math/SHMath.h:39:38: Error  : arithmetic between different enumeration types ('TSHVector<2>::(unnamed enum at Runtime/Core/Public/Math/SHMath.h:37:2)' and 'TSHVector<2>::(unnamed enum at Runtime/Core/Public/Math/SHMath.h:38:2)') is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
> enum { NumSIMDVectors = (MaxSHBasis + NumComponentsPerSIMDVector - 1) / NumComponentsPerSIMDVector };
> ~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 0>/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Math/SHMath.h:460:21: Reference  : in instantiation of template class 'TSHVector<2>' requested here
> inline TSHVector<2> TSHVector<2>::SHBasisFunction(const FVector& Vector)

I tried to disable warnings as errors in the "*.Build.cs" file and in the "BuildConfig.xml" with no success. How to build Unreal Engine 5.1 with c++20 standard?

Additional Information:

- I am on Linux.
- I use JetBrains Rider.
- I did not build from sources.

Comment: Is it ready for C++20? What compiler are you using? Is it a supported compiler?

Comment: I think Unreal Engine is ready for c++20 because they added the enum value for c++20. I am using clang-13.0.1 the version which comes with Unreal Engine.

Comment: Could be a bug, then, but worth checking the [Gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) site first.

Comment: "I tried to disable warnings as errors" Probably not a good idea. Better disable this specific warning.

Answer (score 0):

I meet same issue on UE5.1.1 download from EPIC (also tried build from source code)
any advice?

```cpp
PackagingResults: Error: bitwise operation between different enumeration types ('UMocopiBPLibrary::(unnamed enum at C:/WORK/ownBuild/vrpico1/Plugins/MocopiLiveLink/Source/MocopiLiveLink/Public/MocopiBPLibrary.h:20:2)' and 'EClassFlags') is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
PackagingResults: Error: bitwise operation between different enumeration types ('UMocopiLiveLinkSourceFactory::(unnamed enum at C:/WORK/ownBuild/vrpico1/Plugins/MocopiLiveLink/Source/MocopiLiveLink/Private/MocopiLiveLinkSourceFactory.h:19:2)' and 'EClassFlags') is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
PackagingResults: Error: bitwise operation between different enumeration types ('UMocopiRemapAsset::(unnamed enum at C:/WORK/ownBuild/vrpico1/Plugins/MocopiLiveLink/Source/MocopiLiveLink/Public/MocopiRemapAsset.h:19:2)' and 'EClassFlags') is deprecated [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion]
```

and this only apper when I package apk file, package exe won't emit this error

I'm trying to add:

```cpp
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmacro-redefined"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion"
#endif
```

only  `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmacro-redefined"` worked, because `eprecated-enum-enum-conversion` emit from `.gen.h`, rather than my `.h` file, which I add above code into

Comment: Do not set the c++ standard via a compiler flag. If your desired feature is not in this list "https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/unreal-engine-build-tool-target-reference/" try to not use it. I was lucky and I could change a library my project depends on to not use not supported features.

Comment: @KoronisNeilos  thanks for your advice. I have solved my problem by using `CppStandard = CppStandardVersion.Cpp17`